# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 233 EveryThing is correct, I think

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am learning laravel and I have a problem when I call to delete method.

**My Routes:**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('inicio');
});

Route::resource('secciones', 'seccionesController');
```

**My form:**

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => ['secciones.destroy', $seccion->id], 'method' => 'DELETE']) }}

{{ Form::submit('Delete') }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

The $seccion->id is correct, the secciones.destroy (in seccionesController there are a destroy method ) is correct. When I call delete laravel return me:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 233:
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Try as  `route('secciones.destroy', ['id' => $seccion->id ]) method = "Delete"`

Comment: Your code looks fine. Try to clear route cache with `php artisan route:clear`. If it'll not help, please post result of `php artisan route:list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML Forms don't support DELETE method.
But you can use {{ method_field('DELETE') }}

Also, you forgot to add the {{ csrf_field() }} (token field) in the form.

It will be:

```html
{{ Form::open(['route' => ['secciones.destroy', $seccion->id], 'method' => 'DELETE']) }}

{{ method_field('DELETE') }}
{{ csrf_field() }}

{{ Form::submit('Delete') }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Good luck! :)

Comment: `Form::open()` will generate method field and CSRF token field, so your code doesn't make any sense.